# Phase difference clarification

Tags: waves

In the following diagram what is the phase difference between left and right waves. I mean if the waves were travelling in the same direction it would have been pi. But what in this case?[image]

[image]

Comment: It will remain π as long as wavelengths are equal but wave forms are opposite.

Comment: But what is the reason

Comment: What in the case of second diagram the one with 2 wavelengths

Comment: And it would have been clear whare the waves meet...

Comment: The second figure is shorted figure of the first one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phase difference is defined at a particular moment in time, so at the moment in time that you have drawn, the phase difference is $\pi$.  You can capture the fact that the waves are moving in opposite directions by saying that the frequencies are equal but opposite in sign.